# SQLBackupandFTP monitor

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, database-backups

I have multiple clients that use sqlbackupandftp. I was wondering a solution to monitor the backups of all clients. After some search, I found [Magikmon](http://www.magikmon.com/support/help/backup/sqlbackupandftp-monitoring.en.html). But this "service" is not working and nobody answers to my emails.

There's another solution for my problem?
If I want to develop something like this, what's the best way to do it (which program language)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - this is for MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

We are the developers of [SQLBackupandFTP](https://sqlbackupandftp.com/). In the program check "See backup history on the web" for all your clients and you will be able to see your clients' SQL backup results from a single "web log" page - [more details in this blog post](https://sqlbackupandftp.com/blog/weblog):

[image: SqlBackupAndFTP WebLog]

Alternatively you can use our other product [SqlBak](https://sqlbak.com/), where you can monitor backup results for multiple clients/databases and configure it all on the web as well:

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between SQLBackupAndFTP and SqlBak?

Comment: While SqlBackupAndFTP is a more traditional utility where you configure backup parameters within a program, in SqlBak all interface is on the web. When you have hundreds of servers, it is significantly easier to manage them from one central location accessible from anywhere you have internet.